# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0

Tags: android, android-studio

Im completely new to android studio

I have these configurations :

In **gradle-wrapper.properties** file:

[image]

In **build.gradle** file:

[image]

But when I press **Sync Project With Gradle files** button . Bellow error occurred :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to use versions that don't exist (it seems, you mixed up versions for
two plugins). The correct setup is:

```
classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0"
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0"
```

Comment: after I applied and pres sync again bellow error:
Unsupported class file major version 65

Comment: Try replace version to 8.1.2: `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2"`, according to suitable AS-compatible version

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue trying to build a Kotlin multiplatform app onto iOS. The build worked for android but did not succeeded for iOS and failed with the error above. As pointed out by  @M.G this is can be caused by network issues. Using my mobile hotspot instead of my home network resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

mostly network Issue but for making sure check the link below for compatibility between build version.

https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin

if that was not your issue, it will be network issue.
use VPN that tunnel your device, I mean whole your device.
good example is V2rayNg or any other VPN that tunnel device.

Answer (score 1):

**After going through all this problems yesterday, i later fixed it. But it's quite stressful.**

1. Check if your JDK is compatible with the gradle wrapper version you're using. Although, i made use JDK 20. You can use JDK 21 but i don't know if it'll have enough support for your gradle version, therefore, i'm making use of JDK 20.
   If you're using JDK version 20, then change your distribution url to **8.2.1-bin.zip**
2. Add the Google play services plugin to your build.gradle (app module) file.
3. In the build.gradle (app module) file, change your Java version to **17**
4. Use the latest Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version... The latest version is **8.1.2** although i updated Android studio yesterday.

Change this line in your build.gradle (project) file.

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0"
```

**to**

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2"
```

**Then sync project**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem has solved, when I changed `8.0` -> `8.0.0` for `agp_version`